Why metric subtraction in grafana dashboard return No data?
Prometheus exporter prepare metrics
# HELP selection_cnt_success_by_source Selection count success by source
# TYPE selection_cnt_success_by_source gauge
selection_cnt_success_by_source{source="selection_cnt_success_ui"} 68.0
selection_cnt_success_by_source{source="selection_cnt_success_cvm"} 0.0
selection_cnt_success_by_source{source="selection_cnt_success_tdsk"} 2.0
selection_cnt_success_by_source{source="selection_cnt_success_scheduler"} 8.0
selection_cnt_success_by_source{source="selection_cnt_success_by_source_total"} 78.0

take metrics
selection_cnt_success_by_source{source="selection_cnt_success_ui"} 

by one and use in dashboard - ok

other metrics
selection_cnt_success_by_source{source="selection_cnt_success_by_source_total"}

ok too.

Next I need the metric subtraction
selection_cnt_success_by_source{source="selection_cnt_success_by_source_total"}-selection_cnt_success_by_source{source="selection_cnt_success_ui"}

Try Run query and return No data

How solve this problem?

To solve your specific problem: selection_cnt_success_by_source{source="selection_cnt_success_by_source_total"}- ignoring(source) selection_cnt_success_by_source{source="selection_cnt_success_ui"}. Read more about vector matching

But more generally, your data model is not the best. You should omit total from metrics. If you need total, you can get it with query sum(selection_cnt_success_by_source), and total without one of the statuses: sum(selection_cnt_success_by_sourcee{source!="selection_cnt_success_ui"}). Additionally consider following: rename metric to match namming recommendations - selection_successes_total{status="ui"}. Additionally, if you also expose failures - selection_results_total{status="ui", result="success"}

hmm tried a similar method before registering the question and still returned no data, but now it worked, thanks
